# SQL Ambiguous Column Names

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    OrganizationCode,
    OrganizationDescription,
    FullName,
    EmpNo,
    EmployeeStatus,
    EmploymentStatus,
    CONVERT(varchar, LastHireDate, 101) AS LastHireDate,
    CONVERT(varchar, TerminationDate, 101) AS TerminationDate,
    PositionCodeDescription,
    CONVERT(varchar, POSITIONFROMEFFECTDATE, 101) AS POSITIONFROMEFFECTDATE,
    CONVERT(varchar, POSITIONTOEFFECTDATE, 101) AS POSITIONTOEFFECTDATE,
    TerminationType,
    EmploymentStatusReason,
    CASE
        WHEN EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL 
           THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.LASTHIREDATE, GETDATE()))
           ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.LASTHIREDATE, EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.TERMINATIONDATE) 
    END AS InService,
    CASE
        WHEN VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONTOEFFECTDATE > '01-01-2999' 
             AND EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.TERMINATIONDATE IS NULL 
           THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONFROMEFFECTDATE, GETDATE()))
        WHEN VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONTOEFFECTDATE > '01-01-2999' 
             AND EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.TERMINATIONDATE IS NOT NULL 
           THEN (DATEDIFF(MONTH, VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONFROMEFFECTDATE, EMPLOYEEJOB_CURR.TERMINATIONDATE))
           ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONFROMEFFECTDATE, VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.POSITIONTOEFFECTDATE) 
    END AS [IN_POSITION],
FROM 
    EmployeeJob_Curr, Dept_fac_Curr, VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION
WHERE 
    EmployeeJob_Curr.PositionIdNo = Dept_fac_Curr.PositionIdNo 
    AND VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION.PersonIdNo = EmployeeJob_Curr.PersonIdNo
ORDER BY 
    OrganizationCode ASC
```

I am super new with SQL, please help.

EmpNo, EmployeeStatus, EmploymentStatus, LastHireDate, and TerminationDate all show an error

> Ambiguous Column Names

after I add another view :VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION. Not sure why, before adding it, the query works just fine.

Comment: because you probably have the same named fields in multiple tables/views.  You need to prepend the table/view name to those columns.  ALso I re-formatted your code to make is readable.  Please format code when posting

Comment: Welcome to SO, Aide! It would seem that a column on `VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION` has the same name as some of your other views or your defined `AS` aliases.

Comment: Also, you are using the old style joins.   Try using the new join style, makes your code more readable

Comment: As you're new to SQL it's the best time to learn proper `join` syntax and how to meaningfully *alias* your tables and be *explicit* using `tablealias.columnname` to minimise ambiguity and errors such as this one.

Comment: Your added view must have those three columns also.  After each table in your From clause add a space and a shorthand alias like a, b or c.  Then you can prefix each of your ambiguous columns with a.column, telling SQL which table you want to get it from.

Comment: @Sparky - would that be "new" in the same way that Windows 3.1 is new?

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate this error by using meaningful aliases and `joining` your tables in a clear and concise fashion.

With the example below you would prefix each column in the `select` with either `e.` or `d.` or `v.` depending on which table contains the column - or which table you want to use if a column exists in multiple tables as it does to cause your error.

```
select e.OrganizationCode,
...

FROM EmployeeJob_Curr e
  join Dept_fac_Curr d on d.PositionIdNo=e.PositionIdNo
  join VPERSON_STATUS_POSITION v on v.PersonIdNo=e.PersonIdNo
```